# passing values to modal window on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

the test application which im building has 2 lists of data.

```
1) books 
2) borrower details
```

i list all the available books and if it has been borrowed, i show their name with the status borrowed

**what i'm trying to achieve is,**

when i list all the books, user will be able click and a bootstrap modal will appear. Now it shows the book details on it. But if the book has been borrowed, i need to show the borrowers details such as name, id number... along with the book details.

This is what i have tried

**HTML**

```
<div class="available" ng-repeat="book in books" ng-click="popup(book)">
    {{book.book_name}}
    <div ng-repeat="borrower in borrowers">
        <div class="not_available" ng-show="borrower.book_id==book.book_id>
          {{book.book_name}} is already borrowed by {{borrower.name}}
        </div>
   </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function libcontroller($scope, $modalInstance, book)
{
    $scope.book = book;
}

function testcontroller($scope, $timeout, $modal, $log) {
    $scope.books = []; // custom to pull books from the database
    $scope.borrowers = []; // custom to pull books from the database
    // MODAL WINDOW
    $scope.popup = function(_book) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            controller: "libcontroller",
            templateUrl: 'myContent.html',
            resolve: {
                book: function()
                {
                    return _book;
                }
            }
        });
    };
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Thank you

Comment: What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have the borrowers information in `$scope.borrowers`, his information can be fetched using `Array.prototype.filter()`

```
resolve: {
    book: function () {
        return _book;
    },
    borrowers: function () {
        return $scope.borrowers.filter(function (br) {
            return br.book_id == _book.book_id
        })
    }
}
```

*libcontroller*

```
function libcontroller($scope, $modalInstance, book, borrowers){
    $scope.book = book;
    $scope.borrowers = borrowers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Works perfectly

Comment: a small issue.. I cant access the values individually...when i type `{{borrowers}}` it shows all the values.. But when i try to access individually line `borrowers.name` its always empty

Comment: @Learner, Here `borrowers` is an array. Try `borrowers[0].name `

Comment: on books it shows like this `{"id":"1",` but on borrowers it shows as `[{"id":"1",`  with a square bracket... is it because of that?

Comment: ah.. ok.. its working now.. But do i have to give a value to the array always?

Comment: @Learner, `.filter()` return you an array. It depends how you are creating `borrowers`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the **borrower** for your **_book** through db or some other logic and write it in the `resolve` just like `book`. So the code becomes:

```
$scope.popup = function(_book) {
        var _borrower = YOUR LOGIC TO GET BORROWER FOR BOOK
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            controller: "libcontroller",
            templateUrl: 'myContent.html',
            resolve: {
                book: function()
                {
                    return _book;
                },
                borrowers: function(){
                    return _borrower
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Now you can use `book` and `borrowers` easily in the `libscontroller` by injecting `book` and `_borrowers` as:

```
function libcontroller($scope, $modalInstance, book, borrowers)
{
    $scope.book = book;
    $scope.borrowers = borrowers;
}
```